# Specific scraping data not in source code

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to scrape a specific website, slader, and get the image in a specific div, `solution-content`. I am using requests and beautiful soup, but the problem is that the source code does not have the solutions. Is there a way to get that image?

URL for your reference: [slader.com](https://www.slader.com/textbook/9780321696724-chemistry-the-central-science-12th-edition/694/exercises/1a/)

Comment: The questions and the answers are filled in by Javascript.  It's almost like they don't want you to do what you are doing, which of course is true.

Comment: Right, but is there a way to get around that?

Comment: I can suggest using selenium webdriver to get page content

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

option = Options()
option.add_argument('--headless')
url = 'https://www.slader.com/textbook/9780321696724-chemistry-the-central-science-12th-edition/694/exercises/1a/'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=option)
driver.get(url)
bs = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
print(bs.find_all('div', {'class': 'solution-content'}))
driver.quit()
```